# Trying to prove that if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint cycles and if $\sigma\tau = id$ then $\sigma = id$ and $\tau = id$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be two disjoint cycles in $S_n$, if $\sigma\tau = id $ then, $$\sigma\tau(id) = \sigma(\tau(id)) = \sigma(id) = id$$

Concluding that both $\sigma = id$ and $\tau = id$.

Although I am not really sure I am confident in this answer, have I gone about this problem in the right manner and if not could I get a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a mistake since how do you justify that $\tau $ just disappears in the chain of equalities above???

Also, notice that your argument does not use anywhere the fact that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are cycles nor that they are disjoint. That should certainly make you worry that your proof is wrong. In fact, being cycles is irrelevant for the question. If two disjoint permutations (i.e., no element is moved by both), then if their product is the identity, then each is the identity. For a proof, since $\sigma (\tau (1))=1$, and $\tau (1)\ne 1$, what can it be knowing that $\sigma $ and $\tau $ are disjoint?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, my book has a proof that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute when they are disjoint. The proof is broken broken down into three cases.  I reasoned by contradiction that it can only be 1 of the three cases of that proof.  Which is what I believe you were hinting at it just took some time for me to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $j\leq n$ and $k=\tau(j)$. Suppose $j\neq k$. Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint, $\sigma(k)=k$, but $\sigma(k)=\sigma\tau(j)=j$, so $j=k$, a contradiction. We have proved that $\tau=id$. Now, $\sigma=id$.

Comment: Are you assuming $k\neq j$ without stating it?

Comment: You are right. I'll add this.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that we say that $i$ is in the *support* of $\tau$ if  $\tau(i)\ne i$ and $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are disjoint means that their support are disjoint.

Now assume that the support of $\sigma$ isn't empty and let $i$ in this support so
$$i=\sigma(\tau(i))=\sigma(i)$$
which's a contradiction. We conclude that $\sigma=\operatorname{id}$. The same proof is valid for $\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

As Ittay Weiss noted, your proof is incorrect. A correct one could be as follows :

Let $S$ be the support of $\sigma$, and let $T$ be the support of $\tau$. By hypothesis, $S$ and $T$ are disjoint. Let $t\in T$. Then $\tau(t)\in T$, and hence
$\tau(t)\not\in S$, so $\sigma(\tau(t))=\tau(t)$. But we also know that $\sigma(\tau(t))=t$, so $T$ must be empty ...

Answer (score 0):

You've got several answers, but it seems no one has explicitly noted that if $\sigma\tau = 1$ and the permutations $\sigma$, $\tau$ are disjointly-supported, then (i) $\sigma = \tau^{-1}$ and (ii) $\sigma$, $\tau^{-1}$ are disjointly-supported (though of course all the proofs boil down to this fact).

Comment: What do you mean by disjointly-supported?

Comment: Sami Ben Romdhane defined the relevant notions, but briefly the _support_ of $\sigma$ is the set $\operatorname{supp}(\sigma)$ of $i$ such that $\sigma(i) \neq i$, and _disjointly-supported_ means $\operatorname{supp}(\sigma) \cap \operatorname{supp}(\tau) = \varnothing$, i.e., no letter is "moved" by both $\sigma$ and $\tau$.